# Operator precedence for IBM DB2

Tags: sql, db2

What are the operator precedence rules for the DB2 RDBMS engine?

I am looking for explicit rules which mention actual operators instead of precedence relations between groups of operators.

I found this document http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_precedenceofoperations.dita via googling, but I am looking for something that goes into more detail, e.g. precedence relations between AND, OR and NOT

Comment: Google:  "operator precedence DB2" and click on the link to the documentation.

Comment: I googled of course, but found only general rules such as this http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_precedenceofoperations.dita I hoped to find something that covers it in more detail via this question.

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate in the question then on the information you are really looking for.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for search-condition operators, then see the Information Center section on [Search conditions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_searchconditionssql.dita?lang=en). Additional details are in the topic, but the basic rules are:

> Search conditions within parentheses are evaluated first. If the order
>   of evaluation is not specified by parentheses, NOT is applied before
>   AND, and AND is applied before OR. The order in which operators at the
>   same precedence level are evaluated is undefined to allow for
>   optimization of search conditions.

Answer (score 1):

From [DB2 for z/OS 10.0.0>DB2 reference information>DB2 SQL>Language elements>Expressions>Precedence of operations](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_precedenceofoperations.dita)

> Expressions within parentheses are evaluated first. When the order of
>   evaluation is not specified by parentheses, prefix operators are
>   applied before multiplication and division, and multiplication,
>   division, and concatenation are applied before addition and
>   subtraction. Operators at the same precedence level are applied from
>   left to right.

Comment: I found this by googling, and hoped to find something that covers the rules in more detail.

Comment: @TimoWestkämper What detail is missing? What would be clearer by adding more words to say the same things?

Comment: For example relative precedence between AND, OR and NOT, which are usually not on the same level

Answer (score 0):

I used a case in my order by and it seemed to work

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE KEY IN (KEY1 , KEY2) ORDER BY
CASE 
     WHEN KEY = KEY1 THEN 1
     ELSE 2
END
```

I haven't check with more than 2 keys.

Answer (score -1):

It's over [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/com.ibm.db2z11.doc.srchz/src/tpc/tsrch_db2z_operatorprecedence.dita). Simple google could help you.

Comment: This seems to be for search arguments, not normal SQL usage.